# Parallelism From Slices

Tags: multithreading, go, parallel-processing, slice

I want to make it run parallel based on number of thread. But the result was not as i expected. I dont know how to make it efficient and fast.

I ended up with this code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    target := os.Args[1]
    thread, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[3])
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[2])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: Please double check if the file " + os.Args[2] + " is exist!")
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    wordlist := strings.Split(string(file), "\n")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    jobs := make(chan string)
    for i := 0; i < thread; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        defer wg.Done()
        for _, word := range wordlist {
            go func(word string) {
                jobs <- word
            }(word)
        }
    }

    go func() {
        for job := range jobs {
            code := visit(target + job)
            fmt.Println(target + job + " - " + strconv.Itoa(code))
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Timer: %s\n", elapsed)
}

func visit(url string) int {
    data, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return data.StatusCode
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**
This is my current results :

```
$ go run test.go http://localhost/ word.txt 2
http://localhost/1 - 404
http://localhost/1 - 404
http://localhost/7 - 404
http://localhost/8 - 404
http://localhost/9 - 404
http://localhost/0 - 404
http://localhost/ - 200
http://localhost/3 - 404
http://localhost/2 - 404
http://localhost/4 - 404
http://localhost/6 - 404
http://localhost/2 - 404
http://localhost/3 - 404
http://localhost/4 - 404
http://localhost/5 - 404
http://localhost/9 - 404
http://localhost/7 - 404
http://localhost/8 - 404
http://localhost/0 - 404
http://localhost/5 - 404
http://localhost/ - 200
http://localhost/6 - 404
```

Comment: Please list the errors you are getting along with the a [minimal, complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to explain your problem.

Comment: You can use buffered channel `jobs := make(chan string, 100)` instead of blocked channel `jobs := make(chan string)`. Also update the `defer` for waitgroup as mentioned by @abhink.

Comment: @abhink oh ok,, sorry. i will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the waitgroup correctly. The `defer`'s in `main`'s for loop are never called since `main` never returns and as a result, `wg.Wait()` call never unblocks.

Put `defer` calls in the goroutine sending the message:

```
// ...
for i := 0; i < thread; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)

    for _, word := range wordlist {
        go func(word string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            jobs <- word
        }(word)
    }
}
// ...
```

Also close the `jobs` channel:

```
// ...
wg.Wait()
close(jobs)
// ...
```

Comment: Hi @abhink, I tried to put it on my code but i have another problem. the the process stopped after x thread.

    $ go run test.go http://localhost/ word.txt 10
    http://localhost/2 - 404
    http://localhost/7 - 404
    http://localhost/3 - 404
    http://localhost/4 - 404
    http://localhost/5 - 404
    http://localhost/6 - 404
    http://localhost/ - 200
    http://localhost/8 - 404
    http://localhost/9 - 404
    Timer: 3.734229ms

Comment: Try closing he `jobs` channel.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new goroutine per new job, not per new job added

Here you're creating a log of goroutines to push only 1 word to channel. This is an overkill for such a simple operation.

```
    for _, word := range wordlist {
        go func(word string) {
            jobs <- word
        }(word)
    }
```

But job with fetching url is more heavier, but start only 1 goroutine for this.

```
go func() {
    for job := range jobs {
        code := visit(target + job)
        fmt.Println(target + job + " - " + strconv.Itoa(code))
    }
}()
```

As @abhink has mentioned you're not using `WaitGroup` correctly. Do `wg.Add(1)` before creating each goroutine and do `wg.Done()` at the end of each goroutine. And of course `wg.Wait()` to wait all running goroutines to finish. Example:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

wg.Add(1)   
go func(param){
    defer wg.Done()
    //...
}(url)

//...

wg.Wait()
```